# WCF: Invalid Security Header

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-binding, wcf-security, fiddler

Usually when I consume a web service I add a service reference, put in the URL for the WSDL, and then finagle my way through the API's.

This time around I get a FaultException with the message: "Invalid security header".

Here is my binding:

```
CustomBinding bindingBNP = new CustomBinding();

SecurityBindingElement securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
securityElement.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128;
securityElement.KeyEntropyMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityKeyEntropyMode.CombinedEntropy;
securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;
securityElement.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;

MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement mtomElement = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10, Encoding.UTF8);

HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
httpsElement.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
httpsElement.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
httpsElement.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
httpsElement.ManualAddressing = false;
httpsElement.ProxyAuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
httpsElement.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
httpsElement.UnsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication = false;
httpsElement.RequireClientCertificate = false;
httpsElement.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;

bindingBNP.Elements.Add(securityElement);
bindingBNP.Elements.Add(mtomElement);
bindingBNP.Elements.Add(httpsElement);
```

Related question: for diagnostic purposes, how do I know what the inbound/outbound communication is?

Fiddler doesn't seem to pick up anything (I guess it would have to be on the server machine, which I'm probably not going to be able to negotiate). WCF tracing only seems to surface communication "milestones" (if that word connotates some flavor of victory I am ways off!).

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler runs on the client:

1. Did you start Fiddler before your client?
2. Did you [configure your application](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configuredotnetapp) to proxy its traffic?
3. Are you sure your WCF is using HTTP as the transport?